# Ticket System + Timer

Tags: java, timer

I'm currently working on an offline Jackpot system for fun, and i got stuck with the ticket problem.
Basically I want it to be (which seems to me like the best way to do it) so for every 10$ a user enters, you'll get 1 ticket. so let's say Jason deposits 250$, then he gets tickets 1-25, Bob deposits 100$ then he gets tickets 26-36. etc etc
then in the end it'd pick a random number and it'd pick a player that has that number in his range.
this is the current code:

```
public class Main {
private static int totalPlayers = 0;
private static int totalMoney = 0;
private static int playerDeposit = 0;
private static ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> botsMoney = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static Timer timer;
private static Random random = new Random();
private static int playerMoney = 500;
private static String playerName;
private static double playerChance;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    onUserEnter();
}

public static boolean onUserEnter(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    playerName = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Money: 500$");
    System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
    try{
        playerDeposit = scan.nextInt();
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println(playerDeposit + " is not a proper number!");
        playerDeposit = 0;
        return false;
    }
    if(playerDeposit <= 0) {
        System.out.println("You can't deposit " + playerDeposit + "$");
        return false;
    }else if(playerDeposit > playerMoney){
        System.out.println("You can't deposit more money than what you have!");
        return false;
    }
    playerMoney -= playerDeposit;
    System.out.println("You now have: " + playerMoney + "$");
    players.add(playerName);
    totalPlayers = players.size();
    totalMoney += playerDeposit;
    System.out.println(totalPlayers + " Players: " + players);
    System.out.println("Total Pot: " + totalMoney + ", Your chances: 100%");
    TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(tasknew, 20000);
    botJoin();
    return true;
}
public static boolean botJoin(){
    botsMoney.add(5355);
    int x = 0;
    while(true){
        int willBotJoin = random.nextInt(1000000000);
        if(willBotJoin <= 2){
            if(players.size() >= 10) {
            break;
            }
            int moneyBotDeposits = random.nextInt(1100);
            botsMoney.add(moneyBotDeposits);
            double tickets = (double) moneyBotDeposits / 10;

            x++;
            players.add("Bob #" + x);
            totalPlayers = players.size();
            totalMoney += moneyBotDeposits;
            System.out.println(totalPlayers + " Players: " + players);
            playerChance = ((double) playerDeposit / totalMoney) * 100;
            System.out.println("Total Pot: " + totalMoney + "$, Your chances: " + playerChance + "%");
        }
    }
    botsPrecentage();
    return true;
}
public static boolean botsPrecentage(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        double botPrecent = ((double) botsMoney.get(i) / totalMoney) * 100;
        String botName = players.get(i);
        System.out.println(botName + " has " + botPrecent + "%");
    }
    System.out.println(playerName + " has " + playerChance + "%");
    return true;
}
```

Also I tried setting up a timer which I don't understand how, I've looked up Timer online but I just can't understand the explanations.

Comment: And what is the Timer for?

Comment: Well it doesn't work / setup but it should countdown from X to 0, and when it's 0, choose the winner.